# virtual table with different parameter types

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions, method-signature

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void f(float) { cout << "Base::f(float)\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    virtual void f(int) { cout << "Derived::f(int)\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Derived *d = new Derived();
  Base *b = d;
  b->f(3.14F);
  d->f(3.14F);
}
```

To my understanding, the virtual table of Derived class is:

```
+-----------------+
| Base::f(float)  |
+-----------------+
| Derived::f(int) |
+-----------------+
```

However, this program outputs:

```
Base::f(float)
Derived::f(int)
```

Why these two are outputting different results? I thought `b` and `d` should be pointing to the same virtual table.

Comment: What exactly would you expect?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really have anything to do with vtables. `Derived::f` does *not* override `Base::f` in this case, it declares a new function which hides `Base::f`.

You can call `Base::f` on a `Derived` instance directly using a qualified call:

```
d->Base::f(3.14F);
```

Or you can expose `Base::f` with a `using` directive:

```
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    using Base::f;
    virtual void f(int) { cout << "Derived::f(int)\n"; }
};
```

With the `using` directive, both the `int` and `float` versions will be considered:

```
d->f(3.14F); //calls Base::f
d->f(3);     //calls Derived::f
```

C++11 introduced the `override` specifier to help diagnose issues such as this. If you make the following change:

```
 void f(int) override { cout << "Derived::f(int)\n"; }
```

then g++ gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:12:18: error: 
    'virtual void Derived::f(int)' marked 'override', but does not override
```

Comment: I wonder how compiler works for `b->f(3.14F);`. I guess it should check vtable of `Derived` because it's possible that `f(float)` is overridden in `d`, if so and since the `Base::f` is hidden, it then find the address of `Base::f()`? Is that correct?

Comment: @Deqing that would be one way to implement it.